# Looking for malware detection dataset

Tags: machine-learning

I'm looking for malware detection dataset. I have found some but they have very few features from the pe headers, which is not helpful for detecting malware as APIs/resource .... It would be better if there is raw files and i extract the features myself in a server.

Comment: What features - or do just want EXE images? And do you want non-malware as well, with the outcomes *this is/isn't*? And how much samples would you require? Please read [What a good request looks like](https://opendata.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/284/how-a-good-data-request-question-should-look-like)

Comment: as i said it would be better if there is exe imgaes dataset. if there isn't i need both malware/legit files and the features are imported/exported apis , characteristics and entropy of sections...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

we created Windows API calls sequence of metamorphic malware. In our research, we have translated the families produced by each of the software into 8 main malware families: Trojan, Backdoor, Downloader, Worms, Spyware Adware, Dropper, Virus.
https://github.com/ocatak/malware_api_class

Answer (score 1):

## Endgame Malware BEnchmark for Research

The **[EMBER](https://github.com/endgameinc/ember)** dataset is a collection of features from PE files that serve as a benchmark dataset for researchers. The EMBER2017 dataset contained features from 1.1 million PE files scanned in or before 2017 and the EMBER2018 dataset contains features from 1 million PE files scanned in or before 2018. This repository makes it easy to reproducibly train the benchmark models, extend the provided feature set, or classify new PE files with the benchmark models.

This paper describes many more details about the dataset: https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.04637
This is the best suitable data set I have found for malware detection.

Comment: Please add description.